# jquery and xhr.abort

Tags: jquery, ajax, firebug, xmlhttprequest, abort

When aborting an ajax request with the xhr that's passed back from the jQuery.ajax function, firebug shows that it's still trying to load that request. It doesn't block any more requests that are made, but it also doesn't show that it ever completes the request.

Is this just a firebug problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that this is just a firebug issue.

I set up a test case at jsbin to see how firebug reacted. If you look at the 'Net' tab, you can see the time and amount of data that was transferred for that request, this indicates that the connection is complete, even if the spinner is still bugging you in the console area.

Here is the test case: http://jsbin.com/isolo

I suggest going to http://jsbin.com/isolo/edit and commenting out each of the last lines as a single test case, and you can see how the Net tab speaks more truth.

Comment: The net tab is a "stop dead" give away... Good call.